# Simplify (p OR NOT q) AND (p OR q)

Tags: logic

(p OR NOT q) AND (p OR q)

The book says it's equal to p. How do I go about doing this? I need to simply it by using the laws of logic. Thank you very much!
[This is the problem, or refer to the title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO9l5.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Use distributive laws if you know them, or a truth table.

Comment: Thank you very much, already knew the truth table approach but it's not required here. The distributive law did it however :)

Answer (score 1):

I see three ways to do it: truth table, distributive law and de Morgan's law. Since you know the first two, let me show you the third way. Consider the negation of the logic expression

$$\overline{(p\lor\neg q)\land(p\lor q)}=\overline{p\lor\neg q}\lor\overline{p\lor q}=(\neg p\land q)\lor(\neg p\land\neg q)=\neg p\land(q\lor\neg q)=\neg p.$$

Therefore the original expression equals $p$, i.e.,

$$(p\lor\neg q)\land(p\lor q)=\neg(\neg p)=p.$$

In my notation $\overline{\cdots}=\neg(\cdots)$ both mean negation.

Answer (score 0):

I feel very dumb, figured it right away after some help from Zach, thank you.

Simply write the expression as p OR (NOT Q AND Q) which is equivalent to p OR c (contradiction) which is equivalent to simply p. Hope it helps!

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50jFv.jpg)